# How many even numbers could be formed

Tags: number-theory, permutations, combinations, decimal-expansion

How many even numbers of three different digits less than $500$ can be formed from the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7$ and $8$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "formed by the integers 1,2,3,4,5,7 and 8"?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far ? What have you tried ? Just trying to understand the context of your question.

Comment: Is it numbers or even numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numbers with the hundreds digit $=4$, there are only two other even digits remaining ($2,8$). So the units place has two choices available. After choosing the units digit, there are $5$ remaining digits to choose from for the tens place. So there are $1\cdot 5\cdot 2=10$ even three digit numbers beginning with $4$. A similar analysis applies to numbers beginning with the digit $2$, giving another $10$ possibilities. As to numbers beginning with any of the odd digits, we see that there are $2$ possibilities for the hundreds place digit, $3$ possibilities for the units digit, thereafter $5$ possibilities for the tens digit yielding $2\cdot 5\cdot 3=30$. So the total number of possibilities is $10+10+30=50$.

Answer (score 0):

100th digit must be $1,2,3,4$, every digit is different. So 
$$4*6*5=120$$